# jScrollPane prevents scrollLeft() and scrollTop() value from updating -- how to force update?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I currently have two `jQuery scripts` running on a single div -- one is an instance of `jScrollPane`, and the other is a `custom script` that relies on the current value of of `scrollLeft()` insdie the div.

Only one of these scripts could work at once. After a lot of digging around, I found that when `jScrollPane` was running, the value of `scrollLeft()` has failed to update when I scrolled inside the div.

After a scan through the [jquery.jscrollpane.js](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.jscrollpane.js) file, I couldn't find any instance where `scrollLeft()` was fixed, but I could be wrong.

Is there any way I could force the `scrollLeft()` value to continuously update itself in spite of whatever `jScrollPane` is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! So after more digging we find: `jScrollPane` doesn't actually scroll the content -- it emulates scrolling but continuously resetting the `left` value of whatever it's applied to. So, if you need the value of `scrollLeft()`, you can get it with `jScrollPane`'s `getContentPositionX()` function.

Note that when you do use this function, one must first call `.data('jsp')`, like such:

```
var scrollLeft = $('#div-id').data('jsp').getContentPositionX();
```

Also note that this works the same for `scrollTop()` and `getContentPositionY()`.

`scrollLeft()` never updated because we were never really scrolling.